# Is there always a center of mass of every object and is that point unique?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

I've khown the word "center of mass" for a long time. But now, I have 2 question about it:

**Question 1:** Is there always a center of mass of any object in any dimension?

**Question 2:** For the object that has the center of mass, is that point unique?

Comment: I think [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass) definitely answers point 2, and might answer point 1 but I didn't read it that closely

Comment: The center of mass of a mass distribution $\rho(x)$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined by $$\overline{x}=\dfrac{\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} x\rho(x)\,dV}{\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \rho(x)\,dV}.$$ As long as this integral converges, there exists a unique well-defined $\overline{x}$ for the mass distribution.

Comment: @lioness99a Acually I'm pretty sure that every object has an unique center of mass, but I wonder how can we prove it.

Comment: @LêĐứcMinh It might be worth editing your question to reflect that then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you restrict objects to bounded measurable sets with reasonable density functions, yes.  You can then calculate all the integrals of the form $\frac {\int x\rho\ dV}{\int \rho \ dV}$ and need those integrals well defined.  If the set is not measurable the bottom integral doesn't make sense.  If the object is infinite the integrals may well not converge-you can't find the center of mass of an infinite uniform rod.  If the integrals make sense, the CM is determined and therefore unique.